# How to automate functional programing, and avoid repeating myself

Tags: javascript, gulp, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

Within my gulpfile.js I have the following two functions that are making use of rendering [gulp-nun-jucks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nunjucks) for 2 different views...

```js
function genNunJucks(cb) {
    return src(paths.views.src)
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: ['src/views/'], // String or Array
            ext: '.html',
            inheritExtension: false,
            envOptions: {
                watch: true
            },
            manageEnv: manageEnvironment,
            loaders: null
        }))
        .pipe(htmlbeautify({
            indentSize: 2,
            "eol": "\n",
            "indent_level": 0,
            "preserve_newlines": false
        }))
        .pipe(dest(paths.views.dest))
    cb();
}

function genNunJucks2(cb) {
    return src(paths.views.src2)
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: ['src/views/'], // String or Array
            ext: '.html',
            inheritExtension: false,
            envOptions: {
                watch: true
            },
            manageEnv: manageEnvironment,
            loaders: null
        }))
        .pipe(htmlbeautify({
            indentSize: 2,
            "eol": "\n",
            "indent_level": 0,
            "preserve_newlines": false
        }))
        .pipe(dest(paths.views.dest2))
    cb();
}
```

When it comes to working within the return area of gulp processes, how can I combine these two functions to be one function that does the same job?  You will notice that my `path.views.src(x)` is the reason I am doing duplicating the process.

Perhaps there is there some kind of lopping process that I can apply that looks through a full array of paths.views.src:['','','']?

Many thanks on any tips

Comment: Create a function that accepts params for the things that change?

Comment: Unrelated: this code returns before running the callback. Really don’t need the callback if that’s the case.

Comment: my learning for gulp `return src()` statements is still very young.  I hear you , but don't visually see how yet...

Comment: `paths.views.src2` appears to be a global for example (as does others) - pass those to the function as variables - any time you use globals like this consider that a mental flag to re-factor to use a function parameter. Example: `function genNunJucks(cb, src, dest) {`

Comment: I think I get it now! with all the suggestions.  Simply make a reusable function that calls different parameter values, for a situation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/) and a form of [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) for this, and create a function that gets `src` as parameter and returns the `genNunJucks` that you want to use:

```js
function createGenNumChunksFunction(src) {
  return function genNunJucks(cb) {
    return src(src)
      .pipe(nunjucksRender({
        path: ['src/views/'], // String or Array
        ext: '.html',
        inheritExtension: false,
        envOptions: {
          watch: true
        },
        manageEnv: manageEnvironment,
        loaders: null
      }))
      .pipe(htmlbeautify({
        indentSize: 2,
        "eol": "\n",
        "indent_level": 0,
        "preserve_newlines": false
      }))
      .pipe(dest(paths.views.dest))
    cb();
  }
}
```

And instead of passing `genNunJucks` at the place where you use it right now you can pass `createGenNumChunksFunction(paths.views.src)` and `createGenNumChunksFunction(paths.views.src2)`

Here is a simplified version that can be executed in the snipped and illustrates how it works:

```js
function createGenNumChunksFunction(src) {
  return function genNunJucks() {
    console.log(src)
  }
}

function callPassedFunction(cb) {
  console.log('function will be called')
  cb();
}


callPassedFunction(createGenNumChunksFunction('src1'))
callPassedFunction(createGenNumChunksFunction('src2'))
```

An additional note - which is probably not relevant for your case - if you want to use the `genNunJucks` directly without the need to "create" it first, you could keep it outside of the `createGenNumChunksFunction`.

```js
function genNunJucks(src) {
  console.log(src)
}

function createGenNumChunksFunction(src) {
  return function() {
    return genNunJucks(src)
  }
}

function callPassedFunction(cb) {
  console.log('function will be called')
  cb();
}


callPassedFunction(createGenNumChunksFunction('src1'))
callPassedFunction(createGenNumChunksFunction('src2'))
genNunJucks('src3')
```

Comment: ahh, almost like a reusable function that calls different param values, right?

Comment: @klewis That’s what functions are for 